# Inhomogeneous second-order equation - $y'' + x^{-1}y' = -\frac{n}{\pi}e^{-nx^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am doing a problem in differential equations, but I am struggling with this (basic) ODE on the way.

Given a positive integer $n$, solve $y'' + x^{-1}y' = -\frac{n}{\pi}e^{-nx^2}$ subject to $y(1) = 0$.

The basic approach to solving this is to find a particular solution and then solve the homogeneous version of this.  I struggle with finding a particular solution.  I appreciate any help with this one.

Comment: Let $u=y'$. Then $u'=y''$. Now you have a first order and can solve using your favorite first order techniques...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a first-order equation in disguise. When a second-order equation contains $y''$ and $y'$ but no $y$ you can reduce it to a first-order equation using the substitution $z = y'$. This converts it to

$$z' + x^{-1} z = - \dfrac{n}{\pi} e^{-n x^2}$$

which is a linear equation with $p(x) = x^{-1}$. Find the integrating factor $\mu = e^{\int p(x)dx}$ and its straightforward from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$y''+x^{-1}y'=-\frac{n}{\pi}e^{-nx^{2}}$$
which is equavalent to
$$xy''+y'=-\frac{n}{\pi}xe^{-nx^{2}}$$
which is equavalent to
$$(xy')'=-\frac{n}{\pi}xe^{-nx^{2}}$$
So,
$$xy'=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-nx^{2}}+c_{1}$$
So,
$$y=c_{2}+c_{1}\ln(x)+\int\frac{1}{2x\pi}e^{-nx^{2}}dx$$